# 2 Sources Optimal Path

Tags: graph, dynamic-programming, shortest-path

Let's say we have a R X C table. Each cell contains a weight.

There are two sources in which you can select you can start from ROW 0 but any column.

Your goal is to travel down the table until you reach last row (any column) and there will be no overlapping path. And that must produce lowest weight combined of those 2 path.

Any ideas how to solve? Please let me know if you need more details.

If you can provide some O(constant X R X C) running time, that will be good.

Edit: 
Each step, you can either go left, right or down.

Example

1 9 1 9 
   1 9 1 9 
   1 2 3 9 
   6 3 9 9

Optimal would be 1-1-1-6 and 1-1-3-2-3

Comment: Each step you can move right or down ? or only down ?

Answer (score 0):

As Said by Acess Denied , please specify the rules of travelling down the rows , 
For eg :- if the rule is

`You can either go directly down or right-diagonally down or left diagonally down`

We can do this similar to a Single source problem from the first source , and find the optimal sum , then replace the weight of cells belonging to this path to 0 , and then again run a Single source problem solution from the second source

I think this greedy approach will work as the sum of both paths is asked in final .

Comment: I edit the question already. Btw, there is no overlapping path. If I understand your answer correctly, there will be overlapping path by setting it to zero.

Comment: Ok , my bad , i was trying to find the maximum sum ! 
Instead set the values to 999999 or any high value, that should do the trick of avoiding the already chosen path .Thanks

Comment: Please see my example above, your algorithm probably can't solve the problem. 1-1-1-6 & 1-1-3-2-3 will yield optimal path, but not shortest path (1-1-1-2-3)